# Querying nested Json object in postgres

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column in my table and data is in this format:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "DATA": {
      "a": "XXX",
      "key": "value1"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "DATA": {
      "a": "XXX",
      "key": "value2"
    }
  }
]
```

I would like to get the count of rows in which `key = value1`. I tried some queries like:

```sql
select count(t.id) 
from my_table t, 
jsonb_array_elements(summary->'DATA') elem 
where elem->>'key' = 'value1';
```

It returned 0 rows, though there are rows in db with that key value pair. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `jsonb_array_elements()` for the column `summary` as it is in the form of json array.

```
select count(distinct t.id) 
from my_table t
cross join jsonb_array_elements(summary) elem 
where elem->'DATA'->>'key' = 'value1';
```

Alternatively, you can get rid of the function using `@>` operator:

```
select count(t.id) 
from my_table t
where summary @> '[{"DATA":{"key":"value1"}}]'
```

The second solution should be faster.

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cabd15a0e1c1aa8fde668f8d801d7bfa)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I have a doubt, I came to know about this query: `where (summary @> '[{"DATA":{"key":"value1"}}]')`,  can you explain if this is correct or not? also output of these 2 queries is different.

Comment: @CodePhatGaya - see the updated answer, note I have added `distinct` in the first query.

Comment: yes, that works, thanks for your help. Can you provide any useful resource to study json query in postgres? official postgres documentation is not helpful.

Comment: The official documentation is an absolute foundation that you must know. You'll find lots of good tips here at Stackoverflow. I can't recommend any other useful sources because I never needed them. Tutorials accidentally found on the web are of different quality.